# Killing particle systems in processing with a countdown timer

Tags: java, class, inheritance, logic, processing

Need some help modifying this code. I was working through some tutorials on particle systems, and I'm currently trying to write seom logic that says:

"If this particle system has been running for 10 seconds, stop adding particles to it. When the last of the particles are dead, and the system is empty,remove it from the systems ArrayList."

What is going on now:
 - The timer counts down and particles stop being added to the particle system except it is acting like a timer for every particle system in the array list.
 - the timer does not reset when you add a new particle system

What I need help with:
 - Where to reset the timer, or re-initialize the timer when you make a new system.
 - only having the timer affect the system its in (rather than all of them on screen)

```
// particle system
class ParticleSystem {

    ArrayList<Particle> plist;
    PVector origin; // An origin point for where particles are birthed
    float c;
    int t;
    int countdown; // 10 seconds.
    boolean end;

    ParticleSystem(float col, int num, PVector v){
        plist = new ArrayList<Particle>();
        origin = v.get();
        c = col;
        end = false;
        countdown = 10;
        t = 10;
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            plist.add(new Particle(c,origin)); 
        }
    }
    void applyForce(PVector force){
        for (Particle p : plist){
            p.applyForce(force);
        }
    }
    void run(){     
        // iterate through array of single particles backwards
        // remove single particles when they are dead. 

        t = countdown-int(millis()/1000);
        print(t);

        for (int i = plist.size()-1; i > 0; i--){
            Particle p = plist.get(i);
            p.run();
            if (p.isDead()){
                plist.remove(i);

            }
        }
        if(t > 0){
            addParticle();
        } else {
            dead();
        }

        //print(plist.size());
    }
    void addParticle(){
        //println("AP: "+r);
        float r = random(1);
        if (r<0.4) {
            plist.add(new SquareParticle(c,origin));
        }else{
            plist.add(new Particle(c,origin));
        }
    }

    boolean dead(){
        if(plist.isEmpty() || plist.size() == 1){
            t = 10;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// main tab
ArrayList<ParticleSystem> systems;

PVector windRight = new PVector(0.1,0);
PVector sortaSpeed = new PVector(0,0.1);
PVector gravity = new PVector(0,0.05);

boolean wR = false;
boolean sP = false;

void setup() {
    size(640,480);
    systems = new ArrayList<ParticleSystem>();
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
  if(!systems.isEmpty()){
      for (int i =0; i < systems.size(); i++){
        ParticleSystem ps = systems.get(i);
        ps.applyForce(gravity);
        ps.run();
        if(wR){
          ps.applyForce(windRight);
        }
        if(sP){
          ps.applyForce(sortaSpeed);
        }

        if(ps.dead()){
          systems.remove(ps);
        }

        //print(systems.size());
      }
  } else {
    fill(255);
    text("'w' controls wind, 'a' controls speed, 's' adds particle systems",1,height-30);
  }



}

void keyPressed() {

  if(key == 'w'){
    wR = true;
  } else if(key == 'a'){
    //print('a');
    sP = true; 
  }else{
    systems.add(new ParticleSystem(random(100,200),10,new PVector(random(10,630),10))); //random(480)
  }
}

void keyReleased(){
  if(key == 'w'){
    wR = false;
  } else if(key == 'a'){
    sP = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now we can't run your code because it contains compiler errors. We don't need to see your entire sketch anyway though, just a small example that gets the point across.

But looking at your code, there is a problem here:

```
 for (int i =0; i < systems.size(); i++){
    ...
    if(ps.dead()){
       systems.remove(ps);
    }
```

Run through an example using a piece of paper and a pencil. Let's say you have 3 `ParticleSystem` instances in your `systems` list, and the loop is on the second one. You then remove the second one, moving the third one into the second index. The next iteration of the loop moves to the third index... but now there's nothing there!

To get around this problem, you could iterate through the `ArrayList` backwards, or better yet, you could use an `Iterator`.

From there it's just a matter of keeping track of each instance's `startTime` and comparing that to `millis()`, which you aren't doing right now.

Here's an MCVE that demonstrates using `millis()` and an `Iterator` to kill off `Particle` instances after 10 seconds:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

ArrayList<Particle> particles = new ArrayList<Particle>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  Iterator<Particle> particleIterator = particles.iterator();
  while (particleIterator.hasNext()) {
    Particle p = particleIterator.next();
    p.draw();
    if (p.isDead()) {
      particleIterator.remove();
    }
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  particles.add(new Particle(mouseX, mouseY));
}

class Particle {
  int startTime;
  float x;
  float y;

  public Particle(float x, float y) {
    startTime = millis();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void draw() {
    x += random(-2, 2);
    y += random(-2, 2);

    ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);
  }

  boolean isDead() {
    return millis() > startTime + 10*1000;
  }
}
```

Note that you'll have to use this logic twice: once for your individual particles, and again for the particle systems themselves. But the logic is the same: record a start time, then compare that to `millis()`, and use an `Iterator` to remove stuff when it has timed out.

Also note that `Iterator` is specific to Java mode. If you want to deploy as JavaScript, you might want to go with the backwards loop approach instead.